# Retrieving an item from DynamoDB based on id

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamodb-queries

I have created a simple crud application using `mern` stack. I can save an item to dynamodb but unable to retrieve the item by `id`. The application uses a simple front-end to `save/edit/delete` items.

app.js

```
app.use('/api/event', event);
```

event.js

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  const params = {
    TableName: EVENTS_TABLE,
    Key: {
      id
    }
  };

  dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'Error retrieving Event' });
    }
    if (result.Item) {
      res.json(result.Item);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ error: `Event with id: ${id} not found` });
    }
  });
});
```

Table model

```
{
    "TableName": "events",
    "KeySchema": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "id",
        "KeyType": "HASH"
      }
    ],
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "id",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      }
    ],
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
    }
}
```

Error:

> id is undefined

My code:
https://github.com/omarhassanhub/mern-event

Angular code: Links of all events

```
<tbody>
  {this.state.events.map(event =>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Link to={`/show/${event._id}`}>{event.date} </Link> </td> <td>{event.time}</td>
    <td>{event.title}</td>
  </tr>
  )}
</tbody>
```

Try to get an `event` by id:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/event/'+this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ event: res.data });
        console.log(this.state.event);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line, you bind a list with wrong data

```
<Link to={`/show/${event._id}`}>{event.date} </Link> </td> <td>{event.time}</td>
```

Your `event` contains `id` field instead of `_id` (You table model said that)

Then, when you try to get the event id at `this.props.match.params.id`  (`axios.get('/api/event/'+this.props.match.params.id)`), `id` will be `undefined`.

To fix this issue, just generate the events list with correct data:

```
<Link to={`/show/${event.id}`}>{event.date} </Link> </td> <td>{event.time}</td>
```

Comment: That worked. I altered the ```id``` in table model. Thank you for your help hoangdv.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define column name of requested key. Change your params object, Key expression with column name and try.

```
const params = {
    TableName: EVENTS_TABLE,
    Key: {
      'id':id
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi unfortunately, I've tried that but that hasn't worked either.